# Como fazer o if de várias variáveis com "ou" funcionar?

Tags: c

Quando executo este programa, eu escolho o inteiro `1` e entra nos dois `if`'s. 
Por que motivo entra no `n==1` e no `n!=1` ao mesmo tempo?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    int n; 
    puts("ESCOLA UMA OPCAO");
    puts("1. opcao1");
    puts("2. opcao2");

    scanf("%d", &n);

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    if(n==1){
        puts("opcao1");
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    if(n==2){
        puts("opcao2");

    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    if( n!=1 || n!=2)
    {
        puts("erro");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não tem `else` algum neste código.

Comment: Não estou entendendo qual é o seu problema, vc poderia editar a pergunta e esclarecer ela um pouco mais?

Comment: Acho que a intenção ai era fazer else if, e não vários ifs.

Comment: @user3903094 sempre vai entrar no `if( n!=1 || n!=2)`, pois a condição é sempre verdadeira. Não tem como `n` ser `1` e `2` ao mesmo tempo. Se `n=1`, a parte `n!=2` é verdadeira, portanto a expressão é verdadeira. Se `n=2`, a parte `n!=1` é verdadeira, portanto a expressão é verdadeira. Se `n` diferente de `1` e `2`, ambas as partes são verdadeiras, portanto, a expressão é verdadeira. O erro é na implantação da lógica, o operador "ou" (`||`) não faz o mínimo sentido neste contexto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para sua lógica funcionar, o que você quer tem que colocar no ultimo if o E

ou seja

```
int n; 
puts("ESCOLA UMA OPCAO");
puts("1. opcao1");
puts("2. opcao2");

scanf("%d", &n);

///////////////////////////////////////////////
if(n==1){
    puts("opcao1");
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////
if(n==2){
    puts("opcao2");

}
///////////////////////////////////////////////
if( n!=1 && n!=2)
{
    puts("erro");
}

return 0;
```

Comment: Tiago, para formatar código, selecione-o clique no icone `{}`

Comment: isso deu certo mas não faz sentido, para entrar no if não teria de verificar as 2 condições n!=1 e n!=2 ao mesmo tempo? eu penso que com o operador de || teria mais sentido. não entendo porquê que quem fez o C fez isto. e então caso eu quisesse verificar as 2 condições ao mesmo tempo n!=1 e n!=2 como seria?

Comment: @user3903094 o compilador ja testa as duas condições para você  `n != 1 e n != 2`, no caso em **C** ficaria desta forma `n!=1 && n!=2`, igual a implementação da resposta, o `&&` significa E, isso que dizer que as duas condições devem ser verdadeiras para satisfazer este critério, ou seja, o valor de `n` deve ser diferente de `1` e de `2`.

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra opção, além da resposta anterior, é utilizar uma estrutura `if-else` encadeada:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    int n;
    puts("ESCOLA UMA OPCAO");
    puts("1. opcao1");
    puts("2. opcao2");

    scanf("%d", &n);

    if(n==1){
        puts("opcao1");
    } else if(n==2) {
        puts("opcao2");
    } else {
        puts("erro");
    };
    return 0;
}
```

Atualização: uma estrutura `switch` também funciona para esse caso e, eventualmente, pode deixar o código mais legível:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    int n;
    puts("ESCOLA UMA OPCAO");
    puts("1. opcao1");
    puts("2. opcao2");

    scanf("%d", &n);

    switch (n) {
        // Caso n seja 1
        case 1:
            puts("opcao1");
            break; // termina

        // Caso n seja 2
        case 2:
            puts("opcao2");
            break; // termina

        // Caso contrário
        default:
            puts("erro");
            break; // termina
    };
}
```

Comment: obrigado eu prefiro a primeira opção, ainda assim não fiquei sem perceber porquê que colocando 1 entra no if (n==1) e também no if(n!=1 || n!=2)

Comment: @user3903094: Por causa do operador OR (`||`). No seu código, com `n=1`, no último `if`a condição `n!=1` é falsa, porém, a condição `n!=2` é verdadeira. `FALSO OU VERDADEIRO = VERDADEIRO`, portanto, ele entrar no último `if`.